# The function median of pandas in pyspark is providing wrong answer

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

```py
import pyspark.pandas as ps
psFrame = ps.DataFrame({
    'a': [24, 21, 275, 33, 26,90], 'b': [1, 2, 6,9,4, 6]}, columns=['a', 'b'])

print(psFrame['b'].median())
```

I have the above code running on spark which will find median of column `b`. When i run the code then i got `4.0` as median, but it should be `5`.

Comment: see explanation in the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.median.html#pyspark-pandas-dataframe-median). they're not the same -- *it is an approximated median based upon approximate percentile computation*

Comment: It’s retuning the same answer even putting `print(psFrame['b'].median(accuracy=1))`

Comment: because it is still an approximation unlike pandas

Comment: also, median is internally using `percentile_approx` and looks like it only returns the value from the original dataframe. In case of even number of records, it won't take mean of the 2 numbers (instead taking a smaller number).  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html?highlight=percentile_approx